# Как скрыть и сделать неактивной кнопку android?

Tags: android, if, android-button

У меня есть приложение на андроид с двумя кнопками, и мне нужно сделать одну кнопку неактивной а другую скрыть, при достижении определенного значения счетчика, данное значение отличается и для каждой кнопки свое, я вроде сделал счетчик нажатий на кнопку, но почему-то у меня кнопка либо скрывается и не показывается либо, не скрывается вообще. Вот мой код который я на данный момент сделал:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button plus, minus;
    TextView count;
    Integer clickcount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        plus = findViewById(R.id.max);
        minus = findViewById(R.id.min);
        count = findViewById(R.id.num);

        // Create and set Android Fragment as default.
        Fragment firstFragment = new First();
        this.setDefaultFragment(firstFragment);
        count.setText("1");

        if (clickcount == 3) {
            plus.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (clickcount > 0 && clickcount < 3) {
            plus.setEnabled(true);
        }

        if (clickcount == 0) {
            minus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (clickcount > 1) {
            minus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickcount = clickcount + 1;
                if (clickcount == 1) {
                    Fragment firstFragment = new First();
                    replaceFragment(firstFragment);
                    count.setText("1");
                }
                if (clickcount == 2) {
                    Fragment secondscreen = new Second();
                    replaceFragment(secondscreen);
                    count.setText("2");
                }
                if (clickcount == 3) {
                    Fragment thirdscreen = new Third();
                    replaceFragment(thirdscreen);
                    count.setText("3");
                }
            }
        });

        minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickcount = clickcount - 1;
                if (clickcount == 2) {

                    Fragment secondscreen = new Second();
                    replaceFragment(secondscreen);
                    count.setText("2");
                }
                if (clickcount == 1) {
                    Fragment firstFragment = new First();
                    replaceFragment(firstFragment);
                    count.setText("1");
                }


            }
        });

    }


    // This method is used to set the default fragment that will be shown.
    private void setDefaultFragment(Fragment defaultFragment) {
        this.replaceFragment(defaultFragment);
    }

    // Replace current Fragment with the destination Fragment.
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment destFragment) {
        // First get FragmentManager object.
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Begin Fragment transaction.
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        // Replace the layout holder with the required Fragment object.
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, destFragment);

        // Commit the Fragment replace action.
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


}
```

То есть как можно понять с кода, мне нужно что-бы кнопка minus исчезала при значении счетчика 0, а кнопка plus становилась просто недоступна при значении 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity
    extends AppCompatActivity
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button plus, minus;
    TextView mCount;
    Integer count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        plus = findViewById(R.id.max);
        minus = findViewById(R.id.min);
        mCount = findViewById(R.id.num);

        // Create and set Android Fragment as default.
        Fragment firstFragment = new First();
        this.setDefaultFragment(firstFragment);
        count = 1;
        mCount.setText(count.toString());

        minus.setOnClickListener(this);
        plus.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.min){
            count--;
        }

        if(view.getId() == R.id.max){
            count++;
        }
        plus.setEnabled(true);
        minus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (count == 1) {
            minus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (count == 3) {
            plus.setEnabled(false);
        }
        mCount.setText(count.toString());

        //Fragments router
        if (count == 1) {
            Fragment firstFragment = new First();
            replaceFragment(firstFragment);
        }
        if (count == 2) {
            Fragment secondscreen = new Second();
            replaceFragment(secondscreen);
        }
        if (count == 3) {
            Fragment thirdscreen = new Third();
            replaceFragment(thirdscreen);
        }
    }

    // This method is used to set the default fragment that will be shown.
    private void setDefaultFragment(Fragment defaultFragment) {
        this.replaceFragment(defaultFragment);
    }

    // Replace current Fragment with the destination Fragment.
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment destFragment) {
        // First get FragmentManager object.
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Begin Fragment transaction.
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        // Replace the layout holder with the required Fragment object.
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, destFragment);

        // Commit the Fragment replace action.
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }


}
```

Comment: В кнопках подчеркивает this и из-за этого приложение не запускается minus.setOnClickListener(this), почему так?

Comment: Надо реализовать интерфейс: `implements View.OnClickListener` добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

в onCreate

```
minus.setOnClickListener(this);
plus.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Переопределяем метод onClick и там делаем реализацию.
я не совсем понимаю что именно вы хотите сделать но проверки  на кликабельность и видимость должны быть при кажном клике , а не в onCreate

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (clickcount == 3) {
        plus.setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (clickcount > 0 && clickcount < 3) {
        plus.setEnabled(true);
    }

    if (clickcount == 0) {
        minus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (clickcount > 1) {
        minus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.minus:
             clickcount--;
            if (clickcount == 2) {
                Fragment secondscreen = new Second();
                replaceFragment(secondscreen);
                count.setText("2");
            }
            if (clickcount == 1) {
                Fragment firstFragment = new First();
                replaceFragment(firstFragment);
                count.setText("1");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.plus:
            clickcount++;
            if (clickcount == 1) {
                Fragment firstFragment = new First();
                replaceFragment(firstFragment);
                count.setText("1");
            }
            if (clickcount == 2) {
                Fragment secondscreen = new Second();
                replaceFragment(secondscreen);
                count.setText("2");
            }
            if (clickcount == 3) {
                Fragment thirdscreen = new Third();
                replaceFragment(thirdscreen);
                count.setText("3");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: clickcount++; а если нажат минус?

Comment: если нажат минус то clickout--

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko это поменять елементарно. просто в кейсы перенести clickcount. я поправил.

Comment: ну в целом я приблизительно понял, хотя ваш код не хотя ваш код не хочет работать, я понял логику предложенного вами решения.